# Updating remote database from local database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an application that has a local SQL database.

Then I have an API that would be used as my remote database.

Is there anyway for me inside mvc that when I update something in my local database, it would automatically update in the remote database (the API)?

Any information on how I can further research this topic (I am not finding anything useful using my searches)?

Comment: What is your question? You have 2 instances. You need to immigrate the data from remote to local...?

Comment: I guess my question is... How would I go about "syncing" the local database with the remote one.  Right now they both have the same tables and relations and all.  I am just confused on how to get the local one to inherit the data from the remote one.

Comment: What db is that? Sql? Nosql? Document based?

Comment: SQL for both the remote and local.  Same exact tables and all.

Comment: What database do you have in local and remote?

Comment: Do you have access to db via tool like management studio or a way to export the tables with sql query?

Comment: @Shawn I think you mean Microsoft's SQL Server.  An important distinction because SQL is just the Structured Query _Language_.

Comment: What's wrong with replication?

Comment: @dean what is replication ? maybe he does not have access to the DB itself, e.g i have a project right now that i need to immigrate data from SQL to NoSQL, and i dont have access to the SQL, i have access only to the Rest API URL to query that DB.. so i create immigration tool, ofcourse it would be easy if both instances are microsoft sql server to import/export the db

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx. Might or might not work for Shawn, too little information.